# Why my "where condition" with numeric is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, where-clause, numeric

I'm working with php5+ and MySQL.

I can't figure out why my operation is not working :

```
$prepare = $bbd->prepare('SELECT cm.cm_values FROM c_metas as cm WHERE cm.cm_name = "inscription" AND cm.cm_values > :specific_date');
$prepare->execute(array(':specific_date' => $date));
```

With a fetchAll, this gives me ALL entries with "inscription" in cm_name.
On the other hand :

```
$prepare = $bbd->prepare('SELECT cm.cm_values FROM c_metas as cm WHERE cm.cm_name = "inscription" AND cm.cm_values > '.$date.' ');
$prepare->execute();
```

Perfectly returns entries with "inscription" in cm_name and with a "cm_values" superior to $date...

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong ?

Thx for your help, and forgive my english...

**Edit :** I'm using timestamp to store dates, so $date is numerical.

**Edit again :** as said in comments, there's a trouble with the format of my param. Something like

```
$prepare = $bbd->prepare('SELECT cm.cm_values FROM c_metas as cm WHERE cm.cm_name = "inscription" AND cm.cm_values > :specific_date');
$prepare->bindParam(':specific_date', $date, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepare->execute();
```

works... So I now have to get how to make it works in the execute()...

Comment: I guess in second example you compare `strings` instead of `dates`. `c_metas` is probably EAV table with `cm_values`  column as text. Try: `WHERE CAST(cm.cm_name AS DATE) > `

Comment: I actually use timestamp (oldschool, i know) so specific_date, $date are numericals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,

```
$prepare = $bbd->prepare('SELECT cm.cm_values FROM c_metas as cm WHERE cm.cm_name = "inscription" AND cm.cm_values > :specific_date');
$prepare->bindValue(':specific_date', $date, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepare->execute();
```

fixed the whole thing.
Thx for your answers guys.

Answer (score 0):

"`:specific_date`" is a string and you want to call a variable `$date`. They are different stuff so they turn out to give different results.

Comment: I don't get it. :specific_date is supposed to refer to $date via execute(), isn't it ? (BTW, i'm using timestamp so my dates are numericals)